# Connecting to my data base on mySQL 8.0.19 using VB Net

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, if-statement, try-catch

I have installed MySQL 8.0.19 and create a database named as login_db.
Next, I made a login form in VB Net (VS 2019) and trying to make a connection MySQL database by creating an open connection module:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Module ModuleConnection
    Public connection As SqlConnection ' declaration our connection
    ' function fo connection
    Sub OpenConnection()
        Try

            connection = New SqlConnection(" ")

            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                connection.Open() ' open the connection
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' if failed
            MsgBox("Failed to connect, Error at " & ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

My problem is writing the correct syntax in 'connection = New SqlConnection(" ")'.
The connection details as follow:

Service name: MySQL80
Running on: localhost
Database name: login_db

How to connect to my database using 'connection = New SqlConnection(" ")'?

Answer (score 0):

The `SqlClient` provider is exclusively for SQL Server. If you're connecting to MySQL then you need the MySQL provider - Connector/Net - which you can install into your project as a NuGet package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data

You'll find that most (all?) types have directly corresponding names, e.g. `MySqlConnection` rather than `SqlConnection`.  See [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/) for connection string details.

Comment: Great, I have followed all the suggestions and my project work properly now, so it would be like this: "connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-5VBP3C9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=crud_sqlserver;Integrated Security=True")". Thank you all.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be like that at all. Did you not even read my answer, or did you provider false information in your question? Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? You said MySQL, so why are you now switching to SQL Server?

Comment: I did install MySQL connector and set connection = New MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=vbnet_users_db2;port=3306;password="), Now it works properly

Answer (score 0):

after nuget installation how tell you jmcilhinney,

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html

in this page you can find all about connection of mysql and vb.net....I hope it help

Comment: You would need Connector/Net installed first. There's more information on MySQL connection strings available [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/) too.